# enable and disable date time settings in android

Tags: android

How can I enable and disable date/time settings programmatically ?

Is there any way?

[image]

Comment: You can't disable native setting

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an activity and let user set manually:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: tnx but it is not my answer.

Comment: Ok. So you just wanted me to answer: "it's not possible."? I provided a workaround. You can't change these settings programatically (considering a normal, non-rooted, device).